# Retrieve data based on current ISO week and backwards

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, week-number

I have to work with data retrieved and grouped on a weekly basis (ISO week) and my DB is structured on a daily basis (field: DATE). I need to write down a code which is rolling, so that given the current date, it calculate the week and the retrieve data in the previous 3 weeks, too.

So I write in the WHERE clauses:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'YYYYWW')) BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(running_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYWW'), 'YYYYWW')-3 AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(running_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYWW'), 'YYYYWW')
```

It doesn't seems to work though.
Any suggestions on how to handle the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract 21 days when you want to recive the previous 3 weeks. If you subtract 3 then you recive only the last three days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'IW', not 'WW' as the format mask for ISO week.  From the Oracle docs:

> IW = Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.
>
> WW = Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and
> continues to the seventh day of the year.